# Error al instalar mysql-python

Tags: python, pip

Estoy tratando de instalar con `pip` el modulo `mysql-python` en un Windows 7 Professional.

El caso es que me tira este error:

```
C:\Users\40_027>pip install mysql-python
Collecting mysql-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Installing collected packages: mysql-python
  Running setup.py install for mysql-python ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\40_027\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokeniz
e;__file__='C:\\Users\\40_027\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-qjy4ksg8\\mysql-python\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open',
 open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\40_027\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-mttq0w3y-rec
ord\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    **error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat**

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\40_027\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\4
0_027\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-qjy4ksg8\\mysql-python\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().
replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\40_027\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-mttq0w3y-record\install-record.txt -
-single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\40_027\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-qjy4ksg8\mysql-p
ython\
```

He probado con varias soluciones que he ido viendo por Internet, pero no me ha funcionado nada. He probado a eliminar Python y volver a instalar y tampoco.

¿Me podeis orientar un poco con este tema?

Comment: Gracias @Alan por darle formato al texto. Lo intenté pero no sabia

Comment: No hay problema,  puedes darle el formato de código con el atajo CTRL + K habiendo seleccionado previamente el texto. Abrazo.

Comment: Gracias. ¿Y se puede nombrar a alguna usuario con la @ para darle las gracias y tal o esto no funciona aquí?. Saludos.

Comment: Si funciona. también puedes dar +1 al comentario con si posicionas el puntero del mouse a la izquierda del comentario.

Comment: Pues eso del +1 no me sale.

Comment: ¿Windows 7 de 64 bits? Suena a que tal vez te falte el compilador, el visual studio o el de C++ o algún otro

Comment: Necesitas un compilador de C, como Cygwin. En el paquete que te has bajado lee el fichero INSTALL para saber todo lo que necesitas antes de intentar instalarlo compilándolo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por el error se puede deducir que es un problema de compilación, mencionaste que has probado varias cosas pero no has dicho cuáles son.

Lo que te recomiendo es que instales algo como [Visual Studio Express](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/products/visual-studio-express-vs) e intentes nuevamente la instalación.

Se que suena tonto, pero no olvides tener instalado MySQL.

Otra alternativa es que intentes con [`easy_install`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html) a ver como va.

Answer (score 2):

Como te dice @César, necesitas del compilador [VC++](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/products/visual-studio-express-vs). Que el error diga que no encuentra `vcvarsall.bat` es la evidencia de que no lo tienes instalado.

Si no te quieres complicar, no uses `pip` ni `easy_install` en windows para módulos que necesiten compilación. Busca el instalador de `mysql-python` o, mucho mejor, utiliza [conda](http://conda.pydata.org/) para instalar paquetes python en windows.