# Error al ejecutar pip install mysql-python

Tags: mysql, python, django, python-3.x, pip

estoy intentando ejecutar el comando en windows:

```
pip install mysql-python
```

para poder trabajar con mysql en Django
pero me sale estos errores:

```
  c:\users\fabia\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\include\pyconfig.h(243): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

No encuentro la solución, si alguien sabe algo se lo agradeceria, tengo python 3.5 y visual studio 2015 con VC++ compiler.

Existe un post similar :[Error al instalar mysql-python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6996/error-al-instalar-mysql-python)
pero no me ha dado solución.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otra opción es instalar [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), que te instalará un montón de librerías, entre ellas la que quieres instalar.

Por otra parte, para usar mysql desde python, existe una librería nativa en Python [PySQLdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL), que en mi experiencia es menos problemática a la hora de instalar.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitarás también instalar el SDK de windows que te viene con el Visual Studio 2015. Es ahí donde está el fichero `basestd.h` que te falta.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a descargarte el archivo binario directamente desde la siguiente página:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient

Se trata de una web de la Universidad de California que provee de los archivos binarios para Windows de muchas bibliotecas de Python, especialmente del ámbito científico. Generalmente está muy actualizada (tiene ya las versiones para el nuevo Python 3.6 por ejemplo) y ante problemas de compilación o para instalar Numpy+MKL biene muy bién.

Sigue estos pasos:

❶ Elige la versión para python 3.5 de 32 o 64 bits dependiendo de la que uses.

❷ Una ves descargada te vas al directorio donde este la descarga y abres CMD en ese directorio.

❸ Por último usas pip install seguido del nombre completo (con extensión incluidad) del archivo descargado.

Por ejemplo, si se te descarga en la carpeta Descargas seria algo asi (es solo un ejemplo):

`C:\User\TuUsuario\Dowloads> python -m pip install mysqlclient-1.3.8-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`

No recuerdo si este fork necesitaba de alguna dependencia, si te da algún error por falta de algún módulo solo instalalo con pid antes y luego vuelve a ejecutar la instalación de mysqlclient

Answer (score 0):

Cuando a mí me ha dado error al instalar mysql-python lo he hecho de la siguiente manera:

```sh
sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential

pip install PyMySQL

pip install mysqlclient
```

Así me ha funcionado a mí varias veces y con varios proyectos.

Answer (score -1):

Hace poco encontré un problema similar con un compañero de trabajo. Puedes utilizar:

```
Easy_install MYSQL-python
```

A mí me funcionó.